# Creating an object from two DOM values, not as one key:value set, but two separate sets with manual keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am successfully getting all the DOM data I require into an object, but am struggeling to get each attribute value (id and value) inserted into the object as separate key:value sets.

So currently I console.log out :
{
mo0: '1',
tu0: '1',
we0: '1', ... and so on.

I would like for every iteration to create two key:value sets, using the manual keys fieldId and fieldValue :

fieldId: 'mo0', fieldValue: '1'

```js
        function getTaskData() {
            const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
            const obj = {}

            tasks.forEach(task => {
            const id = task.getAttribute('id');
            const value = task.getAttribute('value');
            obj[id] = value;
            })
        console.log(obj);
        postJSON(obj);
        }
```

Could anyone help revising the code or point me into the right direction please - I have been stuck on it for hours. Many thanks!!

Comment: Note that if you need two manual keys, then you will need an `array` other than an `object`. Then for each task, you can push `arr.push({fieldId:id, fieldValue:value})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an array of sets:

```
function getTaskData() {
    const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
    const sets = [];

    tasks.forEach(task => {
        const id = task.getAttribute('id');
        const value = task.getAttribute('value');
        const set = {};
        set.fieldID = id;
        set.fieldValue = value;
        sets.push(set)
    })

   console.log(sets);
   postJSON(sets);
}
```

You can't have multiple keys in an Object with the same names

Comment: Many thanks. I was unaware - now I am - not :)